# See pages in server,MODX

Tags: server, resources, modx

I am new to coding, trying MODX now.My problem is, I can't see the pages I made on cms back to my server. Is there something I haven't done in order to see them?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

MODX stores all pages(named "resources") in database that's maybe the reason why you can't see them. All chunks, templates, template variables(TV) and snippets(all of them are also involved in the creation of the final page code ) are also in database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this one got it, but still cant find them in server neither with their names nor with their id numbers.For example i made a directory for images, which i see inside server. 
Is there something i have to do, while working on MODX, like make a directory for resources or something inside server?Did i miss something during the setup maybe?
Is it because i bypassed first page and used id2 for homepage?

Thank you all,who help people

Comment: As Anton said, you will not find your pages (called "resources" in MODX) in a directory on the server. They are not .html files. Each resource content is a row in a table in the database, and a resource is made up of several other pieces of data in the database as well (templates, chunks, template variables, etc.). You would need to look at the database to see the content of a resource. But there is usually not a reason to do so unless you are troubleshooting something. All edits would be done through the MODX manager.

Comment: Since you are new to coding you might want to read up on PHP and MySQL. Although you really don't need to know these in order to use MODX, just an understanding of the concepts will do. Learning HTML and CSS will be necessary, so that would be a good place to focus your efforts imo.

Answer (score 0):

MODX have a problems with DB MYSQL(Oracle), but work perfectly with Maria DB. Check your DB type.